# Laravel 5.8 donde se encuentran las rutas de Auth::routes();

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una duda sobre el comando en consola para laravel 5.8:

```
proyecto1>php artisan make:auth
```

cuando entro el comandoen mi documento routes/web.php me crea dos lineas :

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Pero no entiendo donde estan guardadas o conetinidas las rutas de Auth::routes(); para poder jugar con mi login y poder trabajar con este

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se encuentran en el framework, exactamente en vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php , en el método auth():

```
/**
 * Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
 *
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return void
 */
public function auth(array $options = [])
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
    // Registration Routes...
    if ($options['register'] ?? true) {
        $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
        $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
    }
    // Password Reset Routes...
    if ($options['reset'] ?? true) {
        $this->resetPassword();
    }
    // Email Verification Routes...
    if ($options['verify'] ?? false) {
        $this->emailVerification();
    }
}
```

A continuación el enlace de GitHub para Laravel 5.8: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1143

Comment: es un rollo tremendo xD muchisimas gracias! es sufrido un poco ya que el "auto crear" parece un mandamiento en todos los tutoriales y nunca se donde esta todo o donde lo dejo, muchas gracias